# Add new attribute to MagicSuggest div

Tags: magicsuggest

Is it possible to add a new attribute to main div.

for example in html output(by default):

```
<div id="my-id" class="ms-ctn form-control ms-ctn-focus" style="">
    ....
</div>
```

instead (add new-attr="value"):

```
<div new-attr="value" id="my-id" class="ms-ctn form-control ms-ctn-focus" style="">
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: What means that new attribute you need? It will contain the values of the magiSuggest combo ?

Comment: Nope, for another work.

Answer (score -1):

Edit directly the magicsuggest source code for adding that attr, or use jQuery to add that new attribute easily with:

$('my-id').attr('new-attr', 'value');

http://api.jquery.com/attr/